# Build Table with CheckBox with PHP Templating engine

Tags: php, smarty

I am interested to build a table with checkbox, using PHP and [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) ( or any other templating engine):

As one can see some parts of the columns are queried from the database, and the first column is a checkbox. I am pretty sure that this is a common web layout, so I am looking for an open source implementation ( lest I reinvent the wheel).

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: If your interested in using a template engine you should look into Dwoo (dwoo.org). It is like Smarty but with much better performance.

Comment: Why do you want a template engine for that? You can easily do it with pure PHP and with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple HTML:

```
<form action="foo" method="post">
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr><th><input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:FIXME:checkall"/></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[{$id}]"/></td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```